# jquery datepicker Change format

Tags: jquery-ui, csv, d3.js, datepicker, date-formatting

I am filtering my csv data on a simple comparison of d3.csv loaded data with jquery datepicker data.

I'm able to do it finally, except one very silly problem, I am not able to match *single digit dates* because of them being in different formats as shown below :

```
11/09/2015 & 11/9/2015
```

My codes for loading dates :

```
  date= d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse(d.date)  //D3 csv loader
  dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy' //jquery UI
```

How do I go about fixing this small issue? CSV can't change the date loading format, nor can D3. The only option leaves us to mess with *jquery-ui datepicker here*

Any ideas/approach on fixing this issue will be highly appreciated

Comment: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate 
Have a look